# How do I know if the visa is ready for pick up?

Tags: visas, france

I submitted my France visa application 10 days ago. And I have a receipt with a tracking number that looks like this:

```
MONT/010857/0390/03
```

I was asked to log in to [this website](http://www.vfsglobal.com/france/canada/) to check the status. And the status says:

> French: Votre demande de visa MONT/010857/0390/03 a été reçue du Consulat Général de France au Centre de visas à Montréal le 06/06/2018.
>
> English: Your processed application ref no. MONT/010857/0390/03 has been received from the Consulate General of France at France VAC in Montreal.

I didn't choose the mail to door option, which means that I am supposed to go there and pick it up myself. But I find the status above is super vague. What does it mean by "has been received from the Consulate General of France", does it mean that I can go pick it up now?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it does mean that. The VAC has received your documents back. You can collect them.

Answer (score 3):

I think it means your passport has been sent to the VFS office in Montreal. If you live in Montreal, you can pick it up. But if you are not, they still need to mail it to your local VFS office. The VFS staff said they'll send a message to notify the applicant for passport collection. But I read online that many applicants don't receive the message. I guess the best strategy is to call VFS.

Edit: The message I got through the VFS tracking system for passport collection is "Your processed passport is received at the France Visa Application Centre – where you have originally submitted your application. (If you have opted to collect your processed passport from visa application centre, please visit the application centre during collection hours)" Hope this helps.